# mongodb cannot drop database when secondary is down

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, drop-database

I have a replica set with 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter.  When I close secondary member, I cannot drop a database. It waits for something. However, if I open secondary member,   dropDatabase is okay. What is the reason of this? Can't we drop database without any secondary member?

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: What do you mean "When I close secondary member"?

Comment: I tried with 3.6 and 4.0.2 versions. I mean I stop the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since MongoDB 3.6, [`dropDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/) now carries a `writeConcern`. This is set to `majority` by default. This means, in a replicaset cluster of 3, at least 2 data-bearing nodes (not arbiters) need to apply the same change.

If you really want, you can force `dropDatabase` to complete using just one data-bearing node by using a `writeConcern` of `1`. However, this can cause a [rollback](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/).

For more information on `writeConcern` and how to set it, please refer to the docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

Comment: Thank you Robert. This really helped me.

Comment: That's great to hear! Please mark this as the accepted answer if you feel it could help others too.